# How do I clamp values in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, clamp

**Context:**

Calling increaseContrast subtracts 16 from pixels with 0 <= value <= 127 and adds 16 to pixels with 128 <= value <= MAXVAL. Do not allow pixel values to overflow MAXVAL or become negative, **i.e. clamp the pixels to 0 when subtracting and MAXVAL when adding**.

**Method:**

```
public void increaseContrast() {

    }
```

Edit: I apologize for not specifying what I have written under the method, but I can't post my personal program/code because my university will penalize me for plagiarism.

Comment: [`Math.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) and [`Math.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clamping means that you limit your value to a certain range.

You can either manually check if your value exceeds the upper or lower limit and set that limit as new value or you simply use min and max.

```
int minimum = 5;
int maximum = 10;
int value = 29;

if (value < minimum){
  value = minimum;
}
else if (value > maximum){
  value = maximum;
}
```

Or you simply do something like this:

```
value = Math.min(maximum, Math.max(minimum, value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 21, [`Math.clamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#clamp(long,int,int)) is available.

```java
value = Math.clamp(value, minimum, maximum);
```